# Getting warning: control may reach end of non-void function when trying to compile

Tags: c++

This doesn't compile and I don't know the error in this:

```
template<class Type> Type ArrayPQ<Type>::removeMin(void ) throw(exception) 
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "Empty Priority Queue\n";
    }
    else
    {
        Type min = array[0];
        array[0] = array[heap];
        heap--;
        minHeapify(0);
        return min;
    }
}
```

I keep getting this warning:

```
In file included from runtime_analysis.cpp:7:
./PQ3.h:57:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
./PQ3.h:114:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'ArrayPQ<int>::removeMin' requested here
removeMin();
^
runtime_analysis.cpp:67:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'ArrayPQ<int>::DeleteAll' requested here
ArrPQ->DeleteAll();
^
1 warning generated.
```

And whenever I run the code I get an error.

Comment: At least figure out which language you're programming in.

Comment: What's so hard to get from this compiler warning? You should fix your indentation, and it's pretty clear why you get this warning.

Comment: fixed indentation and removed c and c# from tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the warning because you have left open scenarios where a return statement may not be reached. Currently you only have one, in your else statement scope. What will you return outside of the scope of the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

You should throw an exception in case the queue is empty :

```
class myexception: public exception
{
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "Empty Priority Queue";
    }
} myex;
```

then change the is empty check to this:

```
if (isEmpty())
{
    throw myex;
}
```

Comment: He said he is a beginner, so I don't think he know about exceptions.

Comment: a beginner also does not use template classes and specifies throw exception.